# Unable to configure zookeeper

Tags: ubuntu, apache-zookeeper

I am using Ubuntu and going to configure zookeeper on ubuntu. I am unable to run command "bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181"

```
ishwar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/storm/zookeeper-3.4.6$ bin/zkServer.sh start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/ishwar/Desktop/storm/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
ishwar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/storm/zookeeper-3.4.6$ bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
bin/zkCli.sh: line 39: java: command not found
ishwar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/storm/zookeeper-3.4.6$ bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
```

Can any one tell me please why this issue is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could mean 2 things - either **java** is not installed on your system or if java is installed then **JAVA_HOME** is not set. 
Set JAVA_HOME in .bash_profile using something like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/` and then run command `source ~/.bash_profile`. It will set JAVA_HOME and then you can run **zkCli** command.

Comment: Java is installed but still not issue resolved. The issue is resolved by just run both commands in different tabs. I don't reason why this happened.

Answer (score 3):

First run `bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground` instead of `bin/zkServer.sh start` to see that if zookeeper will run.
However, this error is because of not setting JAVA environment variables. to solve that create `conf/java.env` and write proper java environment variables (such that `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/java`) on it. for example:

```
touch conf/java.env
echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk" > conf/java.env
```

Now check that everything is OK!

```
bin/zkServer.sh start
```

and then

```
echo ruok | nc localhost 2181
```

If you didn't install Java please first install it.

Comment: `mkdir` will create a directory rather than the file

Comment: @Tuan Thank you! I edited the post and change 'mkdir' to 'touch'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your zookeeper installation is not able to get JAVA_HOME, make sure you have set JAVA_HOME correctly.

```
mkdir conf/java.env
echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk" > conf/java.env
```

Secondly be very sure about passing configuration file path, and try to start with following command

```
bin/zkServer.sh start
```

Than use following command to connect:

```
bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181
```

From your installation directory, more information [Zookeepr installation on ubuntu.](http://www.techburps.com/articles/download-and-install-apache-zookeepr/36/)